# 'distributor_admin' is not defined as a remote login at the server, login failed for user 'distributor_admin'

Tags: sql-server, database-replication, database-mirroring

I am distributing Database data on SQL Server, I am using Replication but until this picture, I have an error.

I have tried the methods on the internet by that `sp_dropserver` and `sp_addserver` are the same as domain but still cannot.

Everyone who has done it before, please help me, thank you very much.

[image: I create login for distributor_admin]

I create login for **distributor_admin** with Server Role **sysadmin** but it say error:

[image: 'distributor_admin' is not defined as a remote login at the server]

So, I use `EXEC sp_addremotelogin 'dev.dsvinames.com','distributor_admin','distributor_admin'`
then appears an error:

[image: login failed for user 'distributor_admin']

And finally, this is information for SQL Server.

[image]

MS SQL Server Version: `Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583458) - 15.0.2080.9 (X64)   Nov  6 2020 16:50:01   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: )`

Comment: Have you tried adding it as a Linked Server?

Comment: What is the link server for?

Comment: Error 18483 is [a very specific error message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18483-database-engine-error). Has the remote server been restored from a disk image, or renamed since SQL Server was installed?

Comment: I have renamed by sp_dropserver and sp_addserver, make sure i has restart window

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have accessed to server and logged in sql with windows account instead of sa account.
And this works fine for me.
I think sa is not authorized enough to do this even though it has been set full permissions

Comment: I have the same issue while configuring replication. and it's not working for me.

Comment: Do you have login with local account instead of sa?